# "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies...." despite no specific version is given for the package. Why and how can I get around it?

Tags: git, heroku, installation, pip, package

after running: "git push heroku master"

to clone/deploy repository to heroku I am getting following results, terminating with ERROR:

Counting objects: 5109, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.....

:::

:::

```
:::
:::
:::
remote:        Collecting msgpack==0.6.2
remote:          Downloading msgpack-0.6.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (249 kB)
remote:        Collecting phonenumbers
remote:          Downloading phonenumbers-8.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.6 MB)
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_6a369dea83d988aeccf65fbf7cb98921/requirements.txt (line 33)) (from versions: none)
```

remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for pkg-resources==0.0.0
(from -r /tmp/build_6a369dea83d988aeccf65fbf7cb98921/requirements.txt (line 33))

My requirments.txt in the repository says:

```
requirments.txt:


:::
:::
:::
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
msgpack==0.6.2
phonenumbers
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
:::
:::
:::
```

'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no package [`pkg-resources`](https://pypi.org/project/pkg-resources/). The package is a part of [`setuptools`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/tree/master/pkg_resources). You cannot install `pkg-resources` from `requirements.txt`, but you can upgrade `setuptools` if you need.